# C# SSH port forwarding with SSH.net

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

I'm trying to do the following thing in a C# program with SSH.NET :

> ssh -NfD 1080 username@remote.com

Here's the code I produced :

```cs
using (var client = new SshClient("remote.com", "username", "password"))
{
    client.Connect();
    var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 1080, "remote.com", 1080);
    client.AddForwardedPort(port);

    port.Exception += delegate(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString());
    };
    port.Start();
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

I connect to an OpenVPN server through this tunnel. When I use the command line it works fine, but when I use the C# program it's like the tunnel isn't working, even if I can send commands to the server I'm connected to through the C# program.
Any idea ?

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: Not a single one. I have my program listening on 1080 but I can't use the tunnel.

Comment: so `Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString());` never fires?

Comment: No. And when I send a command to the server, it works (for example pwd sends me back /home/username)

Comment: can you provide me an example of something that doesn't work?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to an OpenVPN server through the tunnel.
It works well when I start the SSH tunnel manually (with ssh -NfD 1080 username@remote.com) but not when I use the C# application.

Comment: after `port.Start` try to check if `port.IsStarted` and let me know

Comment: Is your `remote.com` parameter correct?

Comment: IsStarted returns True and yes the remote address is correct.
When I do Console.WriteLine(client.CreateCommand("pwd").Execute()); it returns /home/username so I'm connected to the server

Comment: did you try sending some command with `client.RunCommand("some command");` to see if it fails?

Comment: It works fine with no error
Really strange.

Comment: is it a possible solution to you to use this command? If yes I'll add an answer

Comment: Well I don't know. If I can still connect to my OpenVPN network through the tunnel then yes I guess

Comment: yes until you'll call the close method you will remain connected to your OpenVPN. Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Sorry I was at work, posted a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

the Console.ReadKey(); should be placed in using block to ensure the SshClient instance is not disposed.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new SshClient("host", "name", "pwd"))
        {
            client.Connect();
            var port = new ForwardedPortDynamic(7575);
            client.AddForwardedPort(port);

            port.Exception += delegate (object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString());
            };
            port.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in comments I think that you can try to execute your commands with `client.RunCommand` method in this way

```
client.RunCommand("some command");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer thanks to da_rinkes on SSH.NET forum ([link](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/574658)).

I was using ForwardedPortLocal instead of ForwardedPortDynamic (-D option with ssh command).

Here's the new code :

```cs
public void Start()
{
      using (var client = new SshClient("remote.com", "username", "password"))
      {
           client.KeepAliveInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
           client.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
           client.Connect();
           ForwardedPortDynamic port = new ForwardedPortDynamic("127.0.0.1", 1080);
           client.AddForwardedPort(port);
           port.Exception += delegate(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
           {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString());
           };
           port.Start();
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 60 * 8);
           port.Stop();
           client.Disconnect();
     }
this.Start();
}
```

Still have to find another way to keep the SSH tunnel up (instead of a Sleep + recursive call every 8 hours).

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>