# C# Simple SSH Connection And Send Command to linux host

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssh

I new in programming I am trying to execute some Linux command from c# dotnet via SSH

While searching on the internet I found following code to connect to Linux via ssh

```
SshClient cSSH = new SshClient("192.168.10.144", 22, "root", "pacaritambo");
cSSH.Connect();
SshCommand x = cSSH.RunCommand("start");
cSSH.Disconnect();
cSSH.Dispose();
```

but in my code getting an error cSSH does not contain a definition for Connect also cSSH  does not contain a definition for RunCommand

also, I have installed NuGet package   Install-Package SSH.NET -Version 2016.1.0   for SshClient then also does not work

I also studied and used the following link 
[C# send a simple SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169396/c-sharp-send-a-simple-ssh-command)

[How i can establish connection ssh from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375554/how-i-can-establish-connection-ssh-from-c-sharp/38375806#38375806?newreg=03269b5472d14d4f850ac0f4da0220c1)

Comment: Which namespace does `SshClient` in you code come from?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to send from linux to linux you can execute bash command using this extension method:
https://loune.net/2017/06/running-shell-bash-commands-in-net-core/

Command would look like this: `sshpass -p password ssh ..@.. command`
Here are details: 
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-running-commands-on-a-remote-host.html