# How to Connect to Aurora serverless MySQL instance over SSH

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm not able to find the Aurora MySql Db through an EC2 tunnel.

We have an Aurora serverless Db (MySql). The problem is that I don't know how connect to the db locally from my machine.

I tried to add the SSH options to `mysqlstring` builder like:

```
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder _connectionBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
        {
            UserID = "admin",
            Server = "RDS endpoint in Aws",
            Port = 3306,
            SshHostName = "Ip to the Ec2",
            SshUserName = "the ec2 user",
            SshPort = 22,
            SshKeyFile = @"filepath to local .pem file",
            Database = "db name",
            Password = "db-password"
        };
```

I tried to use both string builder and a sshclient like:

```
 using (var sshClient = new SshClient(_connectionBuilder.SshHostName, 22, _connectionBuilder.SshUserName, new PrivateKeyFile(_connectionBuilder.SshKeyFile)))
            {

                sshClient.Connect();
                // SQL QUERY HERE
                sshClient.Disconnect();
            }
```

The code works and connects when it is released to the lambda instance but not on my local machine.

Works if I open a CMD window and type:

```
ssh -N -L 3306:{aws Db endpoint}:3306 -i {path to .pem} {user}@{ip}
```

And changes server to localhost.

Comment: Are you able to access the machine normally through SSH from your local machine?

Comment: Yes, kinda solved it by using the ssh command in the command window to create a tunnel. Any idea if this is possible to do in code aswell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SSH.NET](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sshnet) for this. You can find a working example [here in the edited question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421094/c-sharp-ssh-port-forwarding-with-ssh-net).

Comment: Aurora serverless is not accessable from a local computer.

Comment: Laimonas I can acctually access it from my local computer throu a ssh tunnel using a ec2 instance

Comment: @MarcusLagerstedt did you try creating a ForwardedPortDynamic object and adding it to the client as in the example provided in the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your database is not accessable publicly.

> PubliclyAccessible Indicates whether the DB instance is an
>   internet-facing instance. If you specify true, AWS CloudFormation
>   creates an instance with a publicly resolvable DNS name, which
>   resolves to a public IP address. If you specify false, AWS
>   CloudFormation creates an internal instance with a DNS name that
>   resolves to a private IP address.

When creating a database make sure to set that it is publicly accessable and it is in a subnet which has an Internet gateway attached.

Also make sure that Security Groups for the database allow connections to your SSH ports (22) and DB tcp ports (3306).

**EDIT**

You CAN NOT access Aurora serverlles outside VPC:

> You can't give an Aurora Serverless DB cluster a public IP address. You can access an Aurora Serverless DB cluster only from within a virtual private cloud (VPC) based on the Amazon VPC service.

Comment: Ahaa, so for me to access it outside of my aws instance i need to set the db to public accessable ? I thought that would make the db insecure. But for development maybe its ok? Will try to change this setting

Comment: I cant seem to find this setting for Aurora Serverless db cluster.

Comment: I have read the documentation about AWS Aurora serverless. What it states - see my original answer - I have edited it.

Comment: No but throu a ssh tunnel it works. No problem when using mysql workbench.